# Voice To Text Software or Format

Tags: media-player

I use IVONA Text to speech to read a text file in English into an audio file (mp3 or ogg), then I use my mobile phone (Android OS) to play and listen to the audio file. Everything is nice just I wish there was a tool which could encode both text and audio in the converting text to audio process, and a player which could open this format and shows what is read as subtitles in my mobile phone.

Or a player which could extract the text from any audio file (or at least those monotonic ones) and show it during the play.

I don't know is there any technology, format or software for Android or Windows or not.

Please guide me

Comment: So you want a software that 1) produces audio from text files 2) reads subtitles from video frames 3) parses audio content and produces text files from that? Or do you want to have a tool that takes a text file and makes a video from it that contains the text as audio as well as text?

Comment: In the best case, i would like a tool that show the subtitle for any audio file (however I know its very hard to extract the text from audio but it could be done for some simpler monotonic audio files), but as I generate the audio file from text then a tool which include both text and the audio and then it can be opened by another player and shows the text as subtitle was great

Comment: What languages do you need the audio -> Text conversion?

Comment: Enlgish, and IVONA was best, however my native language is Persian which I don't think there are a good software for it, plus there aren't good texts in my field in Persian

Comment: A tool like the VLC player for Android will automatically add the subtitles to a video when the subtitle file is named with the same pattern as the video file. I assume other video players do that as well. So maybe you can go the route of making and empty (black) video with audio and subtitles.